# How to place additional text before picture number and name in caption?

Tags: captions

I need to make the caption look like this:

```
   Additional text
Figure 1:Picture name
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: It should be mentioned that you can put pretty much anything inside a figure of table (except other floats) provided it fits on one page.  You can even use `\captionof{table}` in a figure and `\captionof{figure}` in a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it "as usual":

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}

    This is some text
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` command from the `caption` package to achieve what you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Add the following %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}  
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycaptionlabel}{ 
                This is some text before each caption \\ 
                #1 #2
                      } 
\captionsetup{labelformat=mycaptionlabel} 

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \caption{my first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
    \caption{my second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]